# How to convert NUM to INT in R?

Tags: r, int, type-conversion

I am trying to convert numeric format to an integer in R. This is essential to a part of the project where I am using java code to run some simulations (which reads this particular data as int).

I tried both `round(x$var, 0)` and `trunc(x$var)`. Both of them run successfully, but when I `str(x)`, `x$var` is still `num`.  x is a dataframe.

Comment: Perhaps it's java that's the problem?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use `as.integer`:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(5, 0, 100)
x
[1] 26.55087 37.21239 57.28534 90.82078 20.16819


as.integer(x)
[1] 26 37 57 90 20
```

Test for class:

```
xx <- as.integer(x)
str(xx)
 int [1:5] 26 37 57 90 20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `convert` from `hablar` to change a column of the data frame quickly.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hablar)

x <- tibble(var = c(1.34, 4.45, 6.98))

x %>% 
  convert(int(var))
```

gives you:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 1
    var
  <int>
1     1
2     4
3     6
```