# Data is not read properly using data.table::fread

Tags: r, data.table, fread

In `fread("Dummy data.CSV", sep = "~")` :

> Bumped column 22 to type character on data row 19257, field contains
>   'NOT APPLICABLE'. Coercing previously read values in this column from
>   logical, integer or numeric back to character which may not be
>   lossless; e.g., if '00' and '000' occurred before they will now be
>   just '0', and there may be inconsistencies with treatment of ',,' and
>   ',NA,' too (if they occurred in this column before the bump). If this
>   matters please rerun and set 'colClasses' to 'character' for this
>   column. Please note that column type detection uses the first 5 rows,
>   the middle 5 rows and the last 5 rows, so hopefully this message
>   should be very rare. If reporting to datatable-help, please rerun and
>   include the output from verbose=TRUE.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you read the warning? It is quite clear.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an error but a warning. `fread` looks at the beginning, middle and end of the file to guess the datatypes of the columns. Then, when reading the whole file, it may bump into values that do not conform the previously determined data type. In your case column 22 had been guessed as logical, integer or numeric but it contained the string "NOT APPLICABLE". Thus the whole column was turned into character type. `fread` warns you that the data types may not be the ones you would normally expect.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this might be as well an answer.

@paljenczy's answer perfectly explains why you got the warning, then you may use `na.strings = c("NA", "NOT APPLICABLE")` to just turn this field to an `NA`, if this is acceptable. If not, add `colClasses = list(character = 22)` to read the whole column as characters and then process it hovewer you want.

Edit: Just one comment regarding setting this "NOT APPLICABLE" value to `NA`. It might not be a good idea, as not applicable is a piece of information you will loose using the `NA` or casting the whole column to `logical`, `integer` or `numeric`. My approach would be to create a new binary column which will state whether corresponding values in col 22 were given as numbers or "NOT APPLICABLE" and then cast the whole column 22 to any format you want.

Comment: Colclasses worked.  Just more info  when reading the data using Fread can i convert the numeric variable as integer.for ex:- in the data i have 4 variables and one of them is numeric, so using fread(which automatically detects the type of variable) can i import numeric variable as Integer variable.

Comment: Use `colClasses()` with `integer = colNum`, you will just loose some accuracy (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638303/how-to-convert-num-to-int-in-r). And if this worked you can accept the answer to mark that you do not need new ones.